# NodeJs/ExpressJs TLS configuration on load balancer

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, load-balancing, tls1.2

I have 3 app servers running a NodeJS/ExpressJS app and a load balancer in front of them that routes the incoming requests (round robin). This setup is currently http based and we would like to have TLS certificate installed to make it https. Our devops guy has left the company and we have a huge gaping hole on understanding and maintaining this. I am pretty sure this setup does not have Apache or nginx in front of the app servers. So how does load balancing work without ngix or Apache? Does the load balancer have to run on a server by itself? if so is that where we need to install the TLS/SSL certificate ? All servers we use are linux based.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, HTTPS termination happens on load balancer and normal HTTP connection is made between load balancer and server. By doing this, please ensure servers are not publicly exposed (not accessible from internet directly without load balancer).

Install the certificate on load balancer and configure it to make http request from loadbalancer to server. I am assuming you are using some IaaS (such as AWS, GCP etc) and these settings are readily available in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in AWS, either AWS Application Load Balancer is used for load balancing, which is a managed service provided by AWS where you will pay per hour and based on the traffic. Also, it is possible to terminate the TLS/SSL at Load Balancer Level (Where its also possible to use Free SSL Certificates from AWS Certificate Manager).

Since this Load Balancer is a managed service, the High Availability and Fault Tolerance is taken cared by AWS.